# Modifying ElasticSearch score in array string field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using elasticSearch 2.2 whith indexes i can't easily change mappings and I wish do some search request based on keywords.

Here the mappings of my string array field "keywords":

```
"keywords": {
            "type": "string",
            "norms": {
              "enabled": false
            },
            "analyzer": "analyzer_keyword"
```

---

```
 "analyzer_keyword": {
              "filter": "lowercase",
              "tokenizer": "keyword"
            }
```

I want to query it using bool request like it with POST:

```
{
    "query": 
    {

     "bool" : {
        "should" : 
        [
            {
              "term": 
              {
                "keywords": "foo bar",
              }
            },
            {
              "term": 
              {
                "keywords": "baz",
              }
            },
            {
              "term": 
              {
                "keywords": "qux",
              }
            }
        ]

    }


  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields" : {
        "keywords" : {}
    }
  }
}
```

**I will wish the best hits score are hits which contains the maximum of keywords.**

Example of hits sort by score i wish for this request:

1. { id:#x , keywords: ["foo bar","baz"] }
2. { id:#z , keywords: ["foo bar","qux"] }
3. { id:#y , keywords: ["qux"] }
4. { id:#w , keywords: ["baz"] }

But instead i've some results like this:

1. { id:#x , keywords: ["foo bar","baz"] }
2. { id:#y , keywords: ["qux"] }
3. { id:#z , keywords: ["foo bar","qux"] }
4. { id:#w , keywords: ["baz"] }

Do you have an idea can help me to manage it ?

Sorry for my bad english and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Results are sorted by their scores, and those scores depends of many criteria including the frequency of the matching terms in a shard. But you don' t care, you want the same score for all clauses of your conditions, what you can have using:

```
GET /test/test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "keywords": "foo bar"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "keywords": "qux"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "keywords": "baz"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Boost can't help me in this case I think. I want sort by number of keyword match.

Comment: Indeed, I had misunderstood the question and thought you wanted to sort according to the offset of the tag in your query, I've edit my answer. I've learn a lot about the scoring system today, thanks :).

Comment: It works much better but i've always some errors. I will keed this for the moment and try latter.
Thanks for your answer!

Comment: You can use the explain API to understand why a document has is selected/has a given score (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html)